# Query regarding Adobe AEM

Tags: java, adobe, aem

How can I access the history of a Workflow instance using the Adobe AEM api for java?
Say I've created one workflow which contains 3 workitems. I want to access the details associated with all the workitems for that workflow (E.g.Status,Title,User,StartTime,EndTime,Action,Comment).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the following classes.

com.day.cq.workflow.WorkflowSession

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/workflow/WorkflowService.html

and

com.day.cq.workflow.WorkflowSession

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/workflow/WorkflowSession.html

If you want to see a code example on how to filter on a particular workflow instance, you can find a lot of documents in the following file of your AEM instance:

/crx/de/index.jsp#/libs/cq/workflow/components/console/archive/json.jsp

In summary, you will need to create a workflow service and fetch the model to iterate over it's instances to apply relevant filters.

Alternatively, you can write a query to get data from /var/eventing/jobs node which is essentially a workflow instance data store.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you

```
List<HistoryItem> history = workflowSession.getHistory(workItem.getWorkflow());
HistoryItem current;
if (history.size() > 0) {
  HistoryItem current = history.get(history.size() - 1);
  do {
    current = current.getPreviousHistoryItem();
  } while (current != null);
}
```